# What is a Fortune 100 company?

Tags: meaning

An "about the author" section from a computer book:

> Michael Vine has taught computer programming, web design, and database classes at Indiana University/Purdue University in Indianapolis, IN, and at MTI College of Business and Technology in Sacramento, CA. Michael has over 13 years’ experience in the information technology profession. He currently works full time in a **Fortune 100 company** as an IT Project Manager overseeing the development of enterprise data warehouses.

What is a **Fortune 100 company**?

Comment: I think this is General Reference. Googling [**fortune 100**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=fortune+100&rlz=1C1CHFX_en-GBGB569GB569&oq=fortune+100&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.4298j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) produces (hundreds of) millions of results which make it obvious what **Fortune 100** (and **Fortune 500**) companies are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Fortune 100 is a list of the 100 companies that generate the most gross annual revenue ranked in descending order. It however only includes privately-held US-based companies.

A "Fortune 100 company" is a company on that list. It is called "Fortune 100" (Note the capital 'f') because it is published by Fortune magazine.